# How to test ActionText rich_text_field in a System test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to fill in an ActionText rich_text field form input, but can't figure out how to select it. I'm using Rails 6 and ActionText.

With

```
class Activity
    has_rich_text :description
end
```

and _form.rb

```
= f.label :description
= f.rich_text_area :description, class: 'form-control'
```

Test using:

```
fill_in "Description", with: "Some description.."
```

I'll get the error

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "Description" that is not disabled
```

I suspect the problem is with how the Trix editor dynamically fills in this field as you type. I'm just not sure how to do the input, replicating how the user would be entering text.

Answer (score 5):

You can do so by find the trix editor and entering your details manually:

```rb
find(".trix-content").set("New value")
```

Comment: `find("trix-editor").set("new value goes here")`
Works for me. Thank you.

Comment: I need to set it to an empty value, but find("trix-editor").set("") not working.

Answer (score 3):

Since Rails 6.1, you can use the [`fill_in_rich_text_area`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionText/SystemTestHelper.html#method-i-fill_in_rich_text_area) system test helper. Added in [b2b6341374](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b2b634137402a82a7dfd60b5646dbd0860a822ca).